# How can I use the new Date feature in javascript to not display the GMT on my website?

Tags: javascript

This is my code. I am using it in my program to calculate the time difference between this date and the current date so I need to use the `new Date()` function but I don't want it to display the GMT on the website. I just want it to display the date of December 23, 2020.

```js
var createdDate = new Date("December 23, 2020");
document.getElementById("dateCreated").innerHTML = "Date created: " +
  "<br />" + createdDate
```

```html
<span id="dateCreated"></span>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the new Date feature"?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.toLocalDateString()` with the following format options:

```js
const createdDate = new Date("December 23, 2020");
const formattedDate = createdDate.toLocaleDateString('en-US', { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' });
document.getElementById("dateCreated").innerHTML = "Date created: " +
  "<br />" + formattedDate
```

```html
<span id="dateCreated"></span>
```

Comment: :laughs: - I was making that edit when you did it yourself. :)